# How to implement CoordinatorLayout in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, material-design, flutter

Would like some insights on implementing [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) into my flutter project, for a profile page and to hide app bar in tab view:

[What I want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQbRp.gif)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

This is where [`CustomScrollView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) takes place

The example you can find in the doc is fairly good. But in short you'll want to use [`SliverAppBar`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) which can disapear/resize on scroll